# Adding Two containers to main

Tags: java, android

Good day

I am new to android development and I am trying to add 2 containers for fragments in the main xml file, that will each use half of the screen in landscape, but everything I try does not work, please help.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.newProject.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="221dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragments_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you

For landscape mode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="2"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragments_container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml add

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="20dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/frame1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>
 <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/frame2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

in activity class:

```
public void loadFragments(){
    Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    loadFragment(this,fragment1);
    loadFragmentTwo(this,fragment2);

}

public static void loadFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, Fragment newFragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame1, newFragment, getTagForFragment(newFragment)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

public static void loadFragmentTwo(AppCompatActivity activity, Fragment newFragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame2, newFragment, getTagForFragment(newFragment)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
public static String getTagForFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    Log.d("fragment name", "fragment name " + fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    return fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this xml code:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout2"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```